# jslint vim errorformat

Tags: vim, compiler-construction, jslint, errorformat

I have the [jslint](https://github.com/reid/node-jslint) installed with npm on my system.

It produces error messages in the following format:

```
  1 1,9: Missing name in function statement.
    function() {
  2 2,11: Use '===' to compare with '0'.
    if (x == 0) {
  3 4,2: Unnecessary semicolon.
    };
```

I wrote a compiler plugin for Vim to parse the error messages, but I could not figure out the problem with the `errorformat`. I have the following now in my compiler file:

```
CompilerSet makeprg=jslint
      \\ $*
      \\ %
CompilerSet errorformat=
    \%*[\ ]%n\ %l\,%c:\ %m,
    \%-G%.%#
```

Which AFAIK should do the following:

- `%*[\ ]` -- skip the whitespaces in the beginning of the line
- `%n` -- match the error number
- `\` -- skip a space
- `%l` -- match for the line number
- `\,` -- skip the comma
- `%c` -- match the column number
- `:` -- skip the colon
- `\` -- skip the space again
- `%m` -- match the error message
- `,` -- new line
- `%-G%.%#` -- skip all the others

It runs the `jslint` which shows the messages but the `:clist` command does not show any errors.

What am I missing?

Comment: I know there are vim error message patterns on stackoverflow, but I would like to find the problem here, not use a different jslint.

Comment: that comment doesn't make sense. Using an error format in vim is not going to make you use another jslint. The problem here **is** the errorformat (which doesn't match jslint's output)

Comment: There are different vim errorformat strings on the internet but not for _this_ jslint output. I do understand, that the problem is with the errorformat, my question is what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `\,`, the skip comma, the correct format is:

```
CompilerSet errorformat=
    \%*[\ ]%n\ %l%.%c:\ %m,
    \%-G%.%#
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma must be escaped with `\\,` since `,` is a special char in errorformat, and `\` is a special char in vim config file, which must itself be escaped.
To vim, your error format is then `%*[ ]%n %l\,%c: %m,%-G%.%#`, since the `\` at the beginning of the line or before spaces are escapes for vim, not for the error format.